# jQuery change css of an element when another element becomes active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to change the background colour of a label adjacent to an input element when the input becomes 'active'.

This will need to work for both clicking to the input and tabbing between input elements.

I was able to get this to work if the user clicked the input, but my solution didn't work if the user tabbed into an input element. I was also having to repeat the code for each input element. Considering I am likely to have quite a few input elements, I figured there must be a more graceful way?

Here is a link with the basic HTML + CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/xXqhH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lied in my comment - I am going to write this from scratch. I assume the problem you had where it was working with clicking, but not with tabbing, was due to using the `.click()` jQuery function. Using `.focus()` instead, along with a CSS class, should provide the desired result:

jQuery code:

```
$('input:text').focus(function(e) {
    $('label').removeClass('active');
    $(this).prev('label').addClass('active');
});
```

Extra CSS:

```
label.active {
    background: red !important;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xXqhH/2/)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had been using `.click()`. I take it this method is possibly preferable to James's method due to the CSS being visible independent of the script?

Comment: I generally prefer to use classes, but it depends. For a single CSS property, it doesn't make much difference; if you're changing multiple then a class is just that much easier. It does also separate things out that bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, just bind event handlers to the [`focusin`](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [`focusout`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) events. You can use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to find the immediately preceding sibling, and [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) to set a CSS property:

```
$("input").focusin(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").css("background-color", "red");
}).focusout(function() {
    $(this).prev("label").css("background-color", "gray");
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXqhH/1/).